# Why not see the buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The task is to choose the date for a text field. The development is on the iPad, so I use `UIPopover`. But I need two buttons on top. I'm trying to do it, but the buttons are not displayed. In what could be the problem?

Please see screenshot:

[image]

And the full code:

```
dateSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[dateSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0);
UIDatePicker *dayPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[dayPicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
[dateSheet addSubview:dayPicker];
[dayPicker release];

UIToolbar *controlToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, dateSheet.bounds.size.width, 44)];
[controlToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[controlToolBar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *setButton;
setButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Установить" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDateStart:)];
setButton.tag = pTag;
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Отменить" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelDateStart)];
[controlToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, cancelButton, setButton, nil] animated:NO];
[spacer release];
[setButton release];
[cancelButton release];



UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 344)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

dateSheet.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 344);

[popoverView addSubview:dateSheet];
[popoverView addSubview:controlToolBar];
popoverContent.view = popoverView;

popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 244);

popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:changeDateStartField.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[popoverView release];
[popoverContent release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the

```
UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
```

to

```
UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
```

of your spacer button